# Подход к заполнению базы SQLite в Android

Tags: sqlite, arraylist, android-asynctask

Первый раз проектирую базу данных. Приложение получает данные из JSON файла и создаёт объекты данных. Когда или откуда правильно выполнять запросы к базе? Сделать отдельный класс и передавать туда ArrayList с Объектами и оттуда строить таблицы? Или при получении данных не создавать объекты, а сразу писать запросы к базе? Спасибо всем заранее, хотелось бы какой-нибудь наглядный пример. Спасибо